# when i use tensorflow, the error appears: Logs is not a directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter] name:

Tags: python, tensorflow

My codes are here:(mode = 'mlp')

[image]

[image]

I don't know why. I have found this directory in the file, The directory address is

```
"C:\Users\86136\Desktop\2021111873\codes\Logs\mlp"
```

Debug this codes so that it could run successfully.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe it meas some `Logs` in different place.